# what do single quotes do in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I am updating a float column in MySQL and both of the following syntax' work.

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = 0;

UPDATE t1 SET col1 = '0';
```

Isn't the bottom one supposed to break as I am passing a string to a float column ?

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html) a single quote is a string literal.

> > 9.1.1. String Literals A string is a sequence of bytes or characters, enclosed within either single quote (“'”) or double quote
> >     (“"”) characters. Examples:
>
> 'a string' "another string" Quoted strings placed next to each other
>   are concatenated to a single string. The following lines are
>   equivalent:
>
> 'a string' 'a' ' ' 'string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally single quotes delimit string literals or datetime literals.

When you evaluate a string in a numeric context, MySQL takes the numeric value from the leading digits in the string.

```
mysql> select 0 + '123';
+-----------+
| 0 + '123' |
+-----------+
|       123 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If there are additional characters in the string besides digits, they are truncated before the numeric value is calculated. This generates a warning, but the expression still works.

```
mysql> select 0 + '123abc';
+--------------+
| 0 + '123abc' |
+--------------+
|          123 |
+--------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '123abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

String `'1'` is converted to float and then assigned to your column.